# Using "to" as a function word to indicate the result of an action or a process

Tags: prepositions, prepositional-phrases

I encountered a sentence as follows:

> To the audience's consternation, the corpse began to speak.

A bit of googling, brought about this result for the definitions of **to** from [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/to):

***b—used as a function word to indicate the result of an action or a process:***

*to their surprise, the train left on time*

I know the meaning of the sentences but my questions are:

1. Is the phrase beginning with to (up to comma) a prepositional phrase?
2. Is it a valid observation to say that the phrase beginning with to (up to comma) is modifying its adjacent noun (like an adjective)?

Comment: Yes, they are PPs but no, they are not modifiers. They are best treated as supplementary adjuncts, loosely attached elements that are not tightly integrated into the structure of the main clauses.

Comment: re 2, looked at informally, in "to their surprise, the train left on time", it's not the train that is surprising them, it's the fact of the train leaving on time. Hence it doesn't relate to a specific element of the main clause but to the main clause as a whole.